# Cannot register Service Worker in React script

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I am making a basic web app with ReactJS to create push notifications.
I want to let the user the possibility to register manually the service worker by clicking on a button. But nothings happens (no message of success in the console). Did I make a mistake somewhere?

In a standard js file, the code to register the service worker works (without the button though) , but not in the react file.

the code to register the service worker :
[image]

and the event listener on the button : 
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hello, please share the code as text and properly format it

Comment: did you define sw.js can you access it via browser?

Comment: Can you see the images ? This is my first post and i was not allowed to copy an image directly in the post, I thought links would be more handy than text

Comment: Yes, i have a sw.js file in the same root directory as my index.js file

Comment: for future check your question source code to check how to correctly add images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is that you attach an EventListener to `window` that would execute on 'load'. Since this event is most likely already triggered since you can click on a button, the SW is not getting loaded.
Try removing the eventhandler part to directly call the register function.
It would then look something like this:

```
function registerSW() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
    //...
  }
}
```

Another issue I see is that you try to set state by directly assigning it. In react you shouldn't access state like that but rather call `this.setState` like this:

```
// ...
.then(swReg => {
  console.log('SW registered');
  this.setState({ swReg: swReg });
})
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it was linked to the "load" event listener indeed.  But Now I have a problem about MIME type /DOMexception that I ahev to figure out... Anyway, thanks for your help !